# CLI security program via tail

Tags: command-line-interface, audit, tail

I am looking for a cli (command line interface) program that would basically tail either 1 log or a set of logs in /var/log and on the fly output in a more friendly manner. Perl would be best but isn't a prerequisite.

Comment: tail + awk + print doesn't do what you want?

Comment: awk is more awkward to me then vi lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your system has `watch` and you're looking for something quick and dirty:

```
watch '( tail /var/log/logone;/bin/echo -e "\n--------\n";tail /var/log/logtwo )'
```

It's not necessary to use `-f` with `tail` since `watch` updates the display.

There are other better solutions, but if you find yourself in a bind sometimes this kind of thing will help.

Comment: This is more along the lines that I am looking for. Now I just need a wrapper of some sort to pretty up the output somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

[Multitail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitail) allows you to "tail" several files at once. You could also open several windows inside a [`screen`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) session and run `less -F` in each.

As for "output in a more friendly manner", that's very subjective, and also individual for each app. There are log viewers for many popular servers, e.g. [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/). Just see if it does what you need. What exactly do you want to check?

Finally, instead of watching logs, for long-term server maintenance a monitoring software probably makes more sense. Check out e.g. Nagios or ZenOSS.

Comment: As far as I know AWStats is for apache logs. I am looking more for messages and secure. For the "friendly manner" More just filter out some stuff and rearrange and display other things in a different manner like if a line looks like a firewall output display this way.

Comment: Multi-tail is such an awesome app. +1